# Adding and subtracting small numbers OR Addition and Subtraction of Smaller Numbers?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-choice

I am preparing a mathematics syllabus for students, so I need to give a heading like **"Adding and subtracting small numbers OR Addition and Subtraction of Smaller Numbers."** which one is the correct one ?

Comment: Did you mean "Smaller Numbers" in the second phrase?

Comment: @user3169 yes, Smaller Numbers.

Answer (score 3):

They're both correct.

> Adding = Addition
>
> Subtracting = Subtraction

The difference between the two is that `addition` is a noun, whereas `adding` is the present progressive form (gerund) of the verb `to add`

*Addition and Subtraction* sounds a bit more scholarly than *Adding and Subtracting* does.  But it is **not** more scholarly, really.

Answer (score 2):

You are changing two separate things in those statements. The add/subtract change does not affect the meaning at all--both statements are the same--but "small" would be the more typical word vs. "smaller," unless you are specifically referring back to a previous lesson. There is nothing about the add/subtract changes that has any bearing on small vs. smaller.

Comment: Thank you very much, so it's better to use the word "smaller" right ?

Comment: It would depend on the exact context within a syllabus, but most Americans would use "small numbers" in that heading--it is a common two-word mathematics phrase in a way that "smaller numbers" is definitely not.